# Rxjs subscribe not working when subscribing to Behavior Subject in base class

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm currently using Angular 7.

I'm trying to implement a base http service so I can handle every error and show loading gifs all exactly the same. So I have a base service which all my services extend; as soon as a http request is made, I update my Behavior Subject that the page is loading. I subscribe to this `BehaviorSubject` in my `app.component.ts` but it is never triggered in here. Looking online, everyone suggests that my base http service is not a singleton and my `app.component.ts` is subscribing to a different instance of the base service.

I have created a small example on SlackBlitz [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vw7kpn).

When you click the "Change showLoading" button, my subscription seems to work fine in the `BaseServiceService` class but is never triggered in the app.component?

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What you are tyring to achieve is easily done using http interceptors.

Comment: I'd suggest you don't inherit from the base service but instead use / inject the base service in your other services. That way you have access to your base service's functions in all other services and still only use one base service instance that you can subscribe to in your components.

Comment: @Davy excellent suggestion, this is the route I took in the end. Although now I have 2 http interceptors (another for is jwt token interceptor). Is it bad practice to have 2 http interceptors?

Comment: Nope. Not at all. Having one interceptor that does multiple unrelated things would be bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

It's nothing to do with singleton, but suggestions about different instance is correct, I will try to explain step by step.

this two instances (BaseServiceService, FileServiceService)  which you injected in app.component.ts constructor are different and are initialized independently, that's why this.fileService.callBase(); wont interact/trigger this.baseService.showLoading BehaviourSubject, if you change `this.baseService.showLoading.subscribe(x => console.log('new val: ' + x));` this line with `this.fileService.showLoading.subscribe(x => console.log('new val: ' + x));` it will work as you expected, now you can just remove `private baseService: BaseServiceService` injection from constructor and BaseServiceService from `providers: [FileServiceService, BaseServiceService]`

----Edited----

I think i get what you intend to do, so I modified your demo. here is link https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r2wv24

Comment: Good explanation, I understand, but I want to use the base service as this is what every other service will be using. I don't want to subscribe to every showLoading property on every service in my app.component.ts, just a single base service.

Answer (score 0):

Your `FileService` class extends the `BaseService` class, which means both classes will have a property `showLoading`.

Only your `FileService` service is called through the `callBase()` method, which means only the `showLoading` property from your `FileService` will be notified of any change.

I changed this line in your `app.component.ts` to subscribe to the `FileService` instead of the `BaseService` and it works as intended.

```
this.fileService.showLoading.subscribe(x => console.log('new val app: ' + x));
```

I assume you wanted a kind of abstract service to define your `showLoading` at a higher level ?

Comment: Yes I do want an abstract service at a higher level. How can I achieve this with my current scenario?

Comment: I guess not extending `BaseService ` would be the first step, and then having your `FileService` subscribe to your `BaseService` inner observable ?
There are multiple ways to do what you want, but without the big picture in mind it is quite hard to propose a solution based on a mock example...